# Proof Verification: $h(x)$ is a power of $p(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Here is a problem I encountered just before from *Advanced Modern Algebra* by Rotman:

> **A-3.75.** Let $h(x),p(x)\in k[x]$ be monic polynomials, where $k$ is a field. If $p$ is irreducible and every root of $h$ (in an appropriate splitting field) is also a root of $p$, prove that $h(x)=p(x)^m$ for some integer $m\geq 1$. **Hint.** Use induction on $\deg(h)$.

To be honest, I do not think the hint is a good way to tackle on this problem. My argument goes as follows:

**Proof.** Here $p(x)$ is monic and irreducible, so it is precisely the *minimal* polynomial of its roots over $k$.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $h(x)$. By assumption, $\alpha$ is also a root of $p(x)$. Thus, $p(x)\mid h(x)$.

Assume $h(x)=p(x)q(x)$ where $q(x)\in k[x]$. If $q(x)=1$, then we are done; Otherwise, let $\beta$ be a root of $q(x)$. It is also a root of $h(x)$ and even $p(x)$ as well. By similar arguments, we also have $p(x)\mid q(x)$. As we continue, we can see that $h(x)$ is actually a positive power of $p(x)$. $\blacksquare$

Can anyone help to verify if my proof is valid? By the way, I don't see how induction on $\deg(h)$ goes through in this problem. As we can see, any feasible $h(x)$ satisfies $\deg(p(x))\mid\deg(h(x))$ but not all integers satisfy this condition.

Comment: "as we continue" is not a formal argument. You formalize it by using induction

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I agree, but I just want to be concise here. Many textbooks use this ambiguous statement in their "standard" proofs. It is usually hard to get rid of this bad habit ^_^

Comment: A common trivial inductive argument shows that $h$ can be written as a product of monic irreducibles. The hypothesis implies that every irreducible factor is divisible by $p$   so is equal to $p$. QED  $ $ Note that we need only *existence* (not much more difficult uniqueness) of a factorization into inrreducibles.

Comment: @BillDubuque I see. Thank you!